# XCUITest: staticText elements without labels?

Tags: swiftui, xcuitest

I am trying to test for the existence of a particular section header in a SwiftUI Form but, unlike other section headers being created using the same code they do not show up with their label in the element tree - even though they are visible in the UI. For example:

```swift
Form {
  Section(header: Text("this one exists")) {...}
  Section(header: Text("this one does not")) {...}
}
```

In the test, I use:

```swift
XCTAssert(app.tables.staticTexts["this one exists"].waitForExistence(timeout: 5))
XCTAssert(app.tables.staticTexts["this one does not"].waitForExistence(timeout: 5))
```

and the first line succeeds while the second does not. I use the debugger to dump out the element tree and find that the first section produces a staticText with a label that is getting matched while the second does not have a label and the width is zero and the height is different, too?

```swift
StaticText, ..., {{16.0, 266.4}, {343.0, 36.0}}, label: \'this one exists\'
StaticText, ..., {{140.0, 154.4}, {0.0, 14.0}}
```

I have experienced this problem in a number of places in the app we are developing. Section headers that are clearly visible in the UI show up as having no label in the element tree and therefore are not selectable via it in XCUITest.

Any idea how I might even start to investigate this problem? Is there another attribute of the StaticText proxy I could query?

Comment: Is second one visible on screen? Actually needed minimal reproducible example to investigate.

Comment: Yup, both are visible. That is the thing that is so weird. I do not have experience with SwiftUI, just XCUITest, but will see if I can produce a minimal example that shows the problem. I was hoping that this is a known 'feature' with a feasible workaround or that there is some other attribute I could query on? I am not the developer, so am not in control of whether accessibility IDs are assigned.

Comment: Ok, I wrote a minimal app but it does not show the behaviour. I am not sure what to try and extract from the app to make it reproducible but will try.